# NHibernate Equivalent to SQL "UPDATE table SET column = column + ..."

Tags: nhibernate, concurrency

I'm trying to update `Quantity` of a `Product` in a sale system using NHibernate.

```
        using (var session = NHibernateSessionUtil.OpenSession())
        {
            using (var trans = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var product = session.Load<Product>(1);
                product.Quantity += 2;
                session.SaveOrUpdate(product);
                trans.Commit();
            }
        }
```

However, NHibernate will generate an SQL in this form:

```
        UPDATE Product SET quantity = 2 WHERE id = 1;
```

If another client updates product quantity while this code is processing, the quantity will be **incorrect**.
The solution I can think of so far is to lock that row before making the update:

```
                ...
                var product = session.Load<Product>(1);

                // lock row for update
                session.Lock(product, LockMode.Upgrade);

                product.Quantity += 2;
                session.SaveOrUpdate(product);
                ...
```

However, this can affect other client if I need to update a long list of products.

Is there an equivalent method in NHibernate to generate SQL like:

```
    UPDATE Product SET quantity = quantity + 2 WHERE id = 1;
```

?

any suggestion?

***Update***

I've tried opening session with serializable isolation level as @Fran suggested:

```
    ...
    using (var trans = session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
    ...
```

The problem is when the row is modified by another client before this transaction is committed, an exception occurs:

```
    {"ERROR: 40001: could not serialize access due to concurrent update"}
```

*does that mean we need to explicitly lock every row that need updating?* i.e:

```
    var product = session.Load<Product>(1, LockMode.Upgrade);
```

*if the locking is necessary, what is the different between opening transaction with and without **IsolationLevel.Serializable**?*

Comment: this could work: `session.CreateQuery("UPDATE Product SET quantity = quantity + 2 WHERE id = :id").SetParameter("id", 1).ExecuteUpdate();`

Comment: @Firo: this code works, thanks. However, is there any configuration to make NHibernate/Fluent NHibernate generate the SQL rather than we write it manually?

Comment: this is HQL not SQL, but you could check Fran's answer too.

Answer (score 0):

the only way I see doing this is locking the object in a serializable transaction.

so when you open your transactions give it an Isolation level of serializable.  This will lock the object until you commit the transaction.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. I'm new to IsolationLevel.Serializable. Am I doing this correctly? (Please refer to my update)